# C# WinForms: after deploy dynamically setted icon doesn't update

Tags: c#, winforms, icons

I'm having troubles with setting up the application icon dynamically. While debugging in VS2012 everything works fine (icon changes on the application top bar and on the **taskbar**. But when I deploy the application, the icon change on the taskbar doesn't work. In this case the application changes the icon in the top bar (left side) and in the popup after moving the coursor over the taskbar icon - as shown on the screenshot.

[dynamically icon change - proof of concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEx5b.png)

The code is very simple (proof of concept):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private IntPtr hicon;
    private Icon selectedIcon;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void SetUpIcon(Bitmap resource)
    {
        hicon = resource.GetHicon();
        selectedIcon = Icon.FromHandle(hicon);
        this.Icon = selectedIcon;
    }

    private void btnFirstIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bitmap = Resources.Resources.save_main;
        SetUpIcon(bitmap);
        lblStatus.Text = "First icon set up!";
    }

    private void btnSecondIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bitmap = Resources.Resources.search;
        SetUpIcon(bitmap);
        lblStatus.Text = "Second icon set up!";
    }

    private void btnThirdIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bitmap = Resources.Resources.team;
        SetUpIcon(bitmap);
        lblStatus.Text = "Third icon set up!";
    }
```

Thank you for every suggestion how solve this issue. :-)